# How to compile mex on windows 10?

Tags: c++, matlab

I am trying to compile the c++ using matlab, and I have this error:
Error using mex

Please, any advice?

Error:

```
MEX cannot find library 'gsl' specified with the -l option.
MEX looks for a file with one of the names:
gsl.lib
libgsl.lib
Please specify the path to this library with the -L option.
```

MatlabCode:

```
eval(['mex ' GSL_DIR '-O localonly_move.cpp IMG.cpp NormalD.cpp SP.cpp - 
lgsl -lgslcblas -lm -lpthread']);
```

Comment: I think you are missing a `-L`

Comment: @drescherjm -L is here -lpthread before the name of the lib. :)

Comment: That is not what I meant -l is the lib -L is the folder.

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/360705-why-mex-cannot-find-library-m-specified-with-the-l-option